# Refactor asynchronous code in C#

Tags: c#, asynchronous-programming

I got the following code snippet:

```
public Task DistributeAsync(BankAccount account, decimal amount)
{
    lock (account)
    {
        return repository.AddLoanAsync(account, amount).ContinueWith(task => 
        {
            if (!task.Result)
            {
                throw new LoanException();
            }
        }
    }
}

// Somewhere else in the code:
var distributeTask = distributor.DistributeAsync(bankAccount, 42000);
```

And I am wondering how I can rewrite this properly using `async`/`await` keywords for more readability. I am currently facing the issue that I am not allowed to use `await` within the body of a `lock` statement. Any help to get me in the right direction would be appreciated.

I am aware of the lock statement not being thread safe, this snippet is part of a bigger exercise and another question is to explain why that lock does not help making the code thread safe!

Comment: would the async semaphore slim help?

Comment: can you add the calling code in such a way that it demonstrates what you are trying to prevent with the lock?

Comment: @Ewan I am not allowed to use those semaphores. It's just `async` / `await` keywords I am allowed to use. I have discussed this question with my peers, and the gist of it comes down to: move the lock to the AddLoanAsync method within the repository, then you can make the method async and the return type awaitable.

This is all the code I have unfortunately, it's very vague and we already suggested that this might be a trick question, i.e. it is not possible to add async/await without modifying some code (see above).

Comment: what i mean is, why not just remove the lock? why have the function at all when it just calls another function? there must be a dozen 'solutions'

Comment: it seems to me like you are missing some sort of validation, account.balance > 0 or similar and then a later action which would require the lock to prevent the balance changing in between the statements.

Comment: Is AddLoanAsync not thread safe? I would expect it to be. I believe it should be. If it is, then you simply remove the lock, you can refactor to use async/await from there.

Comment: You're overthinking it. Just make `DistributeAsync` async (add the keyword). The rest of the answer will follow. You don't need to change the way things lock.

Answer (score 1):

Use `await` instead of returning `Task` and `ContinueWith` then use `SemaphoreSlim` for locking. Your code without locking should look something like this.

```
if (!(await repository.AddLoanAsync(account, amount)))
{
   throw new LoanException();
}
```

Your should call it like this

```
await distributor.DistributeAsync(bankAccount, 42000);
```

You should only use `return` instead of using `await` when only thing that method does is returning another task.